# Google Analytics API Access with no browser interaction?

Tags: google-analytics

I believe the code below is close to what I need:

```
Credential credential =
        new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(p12FilePath))
        .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
        .build();

Analytics analytics =
        new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Dev API Access")
        .build();
```

However, I am not able to obtain the p12FilePath.

So my questions at this point are is the above code the way to access Google Analytics data in such a way that a browser is not brought up (since I run this as basically a cron job) and as far as the p12FilePath is concerned, is this something I obtain from the Google console directly (is the file downloaded -- I can't see how) or do I take the API key which is provided and create such a file?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the p12 file is done by following the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization

for Service accounts. However, I have been unable to get the code to work.